# Hide js Element

Tags: javascript, element, show-hide

I would like to hide some elements given if conditions. I simply would like them not to show up in the html. I tried with `display: none`. But it seems to be not effective

I was thinking about something like this:

```js
    let beliefs_add_content = function(num_bins, tokens, divid, results = 0, show_submit = 1) {
    let inhtml = ""
    if (results == 1) {
        inhtml += "<div id=\"results_text\">\n";
        if (show_submit == 1) {
            inhtml += "<br>\n";
        }
        inhtml += "<br>\n";
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
    }
    if (results == 1; display: 'none' ) {
        inhtml += "<div id=\"top_div\">\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"question_div\"></div>\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"chart_wapper\">\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"bar_div\">\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"axis_div\"></div>\n";

        for (let i = 1 ; i <= num_bins ; i++) {
            inhtml += "<div class=\"bar_amt\" id=\"bar_amt" + i + "\">0</div>\n";
            inhtml += "<div class=\"div_bar\" id=\"bar" + i + "\"> </div>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"label_div\">\n";
        for (let i = 1 ; i <= num_bins ; i++) {
            inhtml += "<div class=\"label_val\" id=\"label" + i + "\" ></div>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"unallocated\">" + tokens + "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"prob_div\">\n";
        for (let i = 1 ; i <= num_bins ; i++) {
            inhtml += "<div class=\"prob_val\" id=\"prob" + i + "\" ></div>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"amount_div\">\n";
        for (let i = 1 ; i <= num_bins ; i++) {
            inhtml += "<div class=\"amt_val\" id=\"amt" + i + "\" ></div>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<div class=\"slider_div\">\n";
        for (let i = 1 ; i <= num_bins ; i++) {
            inhtml += "\t<div class=\"cell_val\" id=\"cell" + i + "\">\n";
            inhtml += "\t\t<input type=\"range\" name=\"bin" + i + "\" id=\"bin" + i + "\" class=\"form-control slider\" value=\"0\" min=\"0\" max=\"" + tokens + "\" required/>\n";
            inhtml += "\t</div>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<!-- Field for the alternative labels -->\n";
        inhtml += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"labelset\" id=\"labelset\" value=0 class=\"form-control\" required />\n";
        inhtml += "<div class=\"submit_div\">\n";
        inhtml += "<div id=\"submit_message\">&nbsp;</div>\n";
        inhtml += "<table id=\"submit_table\"><tr>\n";
        inhtml += "<td style=\"text-align:left;\">\n";
        if (beliefs_ns.beldat["bin_button"] != "") {
            inhtml += "<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large\" type=\"button\" id=\"alt_button\">Alternate Labels</button>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</td>\n";
        inhtml += "<td style=\"text-align:right;\">\n";
        // We don't show the submit button on the final page
        if (show_submit == 1 & results == 0) {
            let onclick = (results == 0 ? "onclick=\"beliefs_ns.submit_click();\"" : "");
            inhtml += "<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large\" type=\"\" id=\"submit_button\" " + onclick + ">Submit</button>\n";
    }
        inhtml += "</td>\n";
        inhtml += "</tr></table>\n";
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        inhtml += "</div>\n";
        $("#" + divid).html(inhtml);
}
}
```

but it is not working very well. Any suggestions? Do I need to post additional code?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `if (results == 1; display: 'none' ) {`

Comment: After results from user choice have been given in a previous page, I would like not to show all the stuff, which is used to make the choice.

Comment: This is not a valid syntax in javascript. If you want to set an element's style to `none`, you need to use `document.querySelector("YOUR_ELEMENT").style.display = "none"`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "it is not working very well"?

Comment: This `display: 'none'` is not right... in a conditional like it is...

Comment: If i writeif (results == 1; display: 'none' ) what is after the { disappear but also I lose the data.

Comment: @dalelandry thx

Comment: @Parzival could you make an example?

Comment: That's right - `display: 'none'` in an if will not work. Remove that and update the question with what's different between what you get and your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

`$("selector").hide();` will hide the element and then use `.show()` to show it again.

For more info check out https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

I tested it on stack overflow which conveniently has jquery.